# Почему команды перебирающие данные из БД замедляются с каждой итерацией?

Tags: mysql, symfony

Часто нужно выполнить перебор данных из БД. Например миграция данных из одной БД в другую. Выполнение каких-то изменений в БД по крону. Генерация файлов sitemap.xml и RSS.

Проблема в том что первые несколько итераций выполняются за доли секунды, но чем дольше работает перебор данных, тем медленней он это делает.

Пример скрипта миграции данных

```
$progress = $io->createProgressBar($total);
$progress->start();
$progress->setRedrawFrequency($job->getRedraw()); // fix buffer overflow

$strategy = $job->createStrategySave();

for ($i = 0; $i < $chunks; $i++) {
    // get data
    $data = $job
        ->getDataQuery()
        ->setFirstResult($chunk_size * $i)
        ->setMaxResults($chunk_size)
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();

    while ($row = array_shift($data)) {
        $entity = $strategy->getEntity($row);

        $job->fillEntity($entity->getEntity(), $row);

        if ($entity->isNew()) {
            $this->default_em->persist($entity->getEntity());
        }

        unset($row, $entity);
        $progress->advance();
    }
    unset($data);

    $this->default_em->flush();
    // fix doctrine memory leak
    $this->default_em->clear();
    $this->migrate_em->clear();
    gc_collect_cycles();
}

$progress->finish();
$io->newLine(2); // newline on end progress
```

Проблему утечки памяти я решил, но что делать со скоростью я не знаю. Есть мысль что причина в MySQL. На первых итерациях MySQL пишет в память, а дальше начинает сбрасывать данные на диск и из-за этого тормоза.

Понятно что еще тормоза могут быть из-за логирования, но с флагом `--no-debug` оно отключено и тормоза все равно наблюдаются.

**UPDATE 2016-12-30**

Чтоб не быть голословным собрал статистику для одной из программ:

```
1
select: 25.25 MiB - 2 ms
fill: 28.50 MiB - 349 ms
flush: 28.50 MiB - 142 ms

2
select: 28.50 MiB - 5 ms
fill: 28.50 MiB - 582 ms
flush: 28.50 MiB - 227 ms

3
select: 28.50 MiB - 8 ms
fill: 28.50 MiB - 810 ms
flush: 28.50 MiB - 313 ms

4
select: 28.50 MiB - 11 ms
fill: 28.50 MiB - 1036 ms
flush: 28.50 MiB - 400 ms

5
select: 28.50 MiB - 15 ms
fill: 28.50 MiB - 1263 ms
flush: 28.50 MiB - 485 ms

6
select: 28.50 MiB - 18 ms
fill: 28.50 MiB - 1489 ms
flush: 28.50 MiB - 570 ms

7
select: 28.50 MiB - 21 ms
fill: 28.50 MiB - 1732 ms
flush: 28.50 MiB - 664 ms

8
select: 28.50 MiB - 24 ms
fill: 28.50 MiB - 2011 ms
flush: 28.50 MiB - 780 ms

9
select: 28.50 MiB - 27 ms
fill: 30.00 MiB - 2405 ms
flush: 30.00 MiB - 1015 ms

10
select: 30.00 MiB - 31 ms
fill: 30.50 MiB - 2845 ms
flush: 30.50 MiB - 1291 ms

11
select: 30.25 MiB - 35 ms
fill: 30.50 MiB - 3295 ms
flush: 30.50 MiB - 1571 ms

12
select: 30.50 MiB - 40 ms
fill: 30.75 MiB - 3963 ms
flush: 30.75 MiB - 1848 ms

13
select: 30.75 MiB - 43 ms
fill: 30.75 MiB - 4532 ms
flush: 30.75 MiB - 2079 ms


Time: 7.01 s.
Memory: 30.75 MiB.
```

Несколько итераций, в каждой из которых выбирается по 300 записей (`select`) запросом вида:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    davaite_risovat
LIMIT
    300
OFFSET
    3000
```

На основе полученных данных создаются новые записи (`fill`) и пишутся в БД (`flush`).

По результатам явно видно что с каждой итерацией время выполнение всех запросов увеличивается.

Comment: Сколько времени уходит на запросы, согласно профилировщику доктрины? Действительно ли растет время на стороне MySQL?

Comment: @Etki а как посмотреть время запросов из консоли? в лог падают только сами запросы

Comment: я не знаю, но раз дэшборд разработчика их выводит - эта информация доступна

Comment: Посмотрите поддержку такой штуки, как курсор (cursor). Она практически не применяется в php из-за того, что его некому держать (приложение умирает по окончанию запроса), но в консольном приложенийи все должно быть окей.

Comment: @Etki *Мелкий* уже посоветовал использовать [doctrine iterate](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html#iterating-results), но мне кажется что проблема не только в выборке данных

Comment: Если вам кажется, но подтверждений этому нет, это не следует считать за рабочую гипотезу. iterate, судя по описанию - другая штука, она все равно будет работать на клиентской стороне.

Comment: @Etki провел небольшое тестирование и добавил результаты в вопрос

Answer (score 4):

```
->setFirstResult($chunk_size * $i)
```

Который маппится в `offset`. Знаете, как работает offset? Прочитать offset + limit строк, выкинуть первые offset строк, вернуть оставшееся как результат. Ещё надо что-то пояснять, почему каждая следующая итерация всегда будет медленнее предыдущей?

Читайте по какому-нибудь уникальному ключу. Например, если у вас первичный ключ EntityId как сиквенс от 1 и порядок обработки неважен, то алгоритм такой:

1. принять текущий элемент lastId = 0
2. прочитать N элементов по `where EntityId > :lastId order by EntityId limit 100`
3. если список вернулся пустой - завершить цикл
4. обработать список, сохраняя в lastId значение EntityId последнего элемента
5. вернуться на шаг 2 и прочитать следующую пачку записей

---

Зачем вам понадобилось дёргать `array_shift`? Он же переписывает чуть меньше чем весь массив. Обходите массив по нативному двусвязному списку через `foreach`. Чтобы не держать весь блок сущностей в памяти - есть `IterableResult`, который возвращает метод `iterate`

Comment: Про offset как-то забыл. Но выборка по id не будет работать если id у нас в результате не последовательны. Тогда нужно сначало выбрать все id, а потом итерироватся по конкретному списку, а если список id большой то придется использовать дополнительные инструменты для работы с этим списком. `array_shift` делал что бы освобождать память и сохранять порядок записей. Метода `iterate` есть только в ORM QueryBuilder-е, конкретно здесь я использовал DBAL QueryBuilder

Comment: Значит используйте те поля, по которым вы обеспечиваете последовательность выборки. А если вы вообще никаким порядком не озаботились - то у вас проблема не с производительностью, а с логикой работы. Запрос без явной сортировки может давать совершенно любые строки и состояние "обработаны по одному разу все строки" - не более чем случайность.

Comment: У вас же записи всё равно как-то упорядочены, добавьте в конец id. `SELECT ... WHERE (...) AND (field1 >= :lastFiled1 AND field2 >= :lastField2 AND id > :lastId) ORDER BY field1, fileld2 , id`

Comment: Ребят, рандомная выборка не может работать медленнее выборки по какому-то ключу. Ваше добавление айдишника или еще чего-то никак не увеличит производительность по сравнению с простой выборкой. Единственное, что можно посоветовать - это подкинуть индексов, если там используется where по неиндексированным полям.

Comment: @Etki Ну что он не догадается сделать ключ? Или c ключом и offset залетает?

Comment: @Sergey да, если where использовал неиндексированное поле, которое затем стало индексированным - залетает. Но нам неизвестно, есть ли там where или неиндексированные поля.

Comment: @Sergey окей, а если мне для ленты новостей нужно вывести все события отсортированные по дате, но дата может совпадать у новостей и id у них не последовательный. Как мне тогда отличить один кусок выборки от другого? Передавать в запрос дату и id последних записей? `WHERE date >= :date AND id != :id`. А если с одной датой более 2 записи, то другие записи могут попасть в первую выборку и во вторую тоже попадут

Comment: Сортируете по дате и ид: `ORDER BY date, id`. В условии при этом `WHERE date >= :date AND id > :id`. Записи выстроятся последовательно по дате, а у кого дата одинакова, те ещё и по id. Какая разница последовательные они или какие. ORDER BY сделает их последовательными.

Comment: @Etki Что ж, в этом есть какая-то логика. Что искать неизвестно сколько совпадение по ключу, что отсчитывать по нему же offset в N записей, наверное не очень большая разница.

Comment: @Sergey это все конечно здорово, но оптимизировать запрос `SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 1000, 100` без толку. Я думаю тут проблема скорее в записи в БД